# How to make more alarm in game marker

Tags: 2d, game-development, game-maker

Hello am using game maker to create my project. My project has a start button and when you click it, the alarms will go off and run code which i set in the alarm for example.

```
Example, alarm[0] = 30 // set the timer
```

Now in alarm[0] we add code.

```
Create (x,y ,player); // code i want to run when i click the start button.
```

However game maker only has 11 alarms i wanted to know if there were ways to create more alarms like alarm[14] and so on.

Comment: i found the answer just make a random_alarm object and add more alarm and use the with function to call the alarms for the random_alarm object

Answer (score 0):

An alarm is just a variable.

Some scripts for custom alarms:

script `custom_alarms_initialize`. Call it from `Create` event

```
/// custom_alarms_initialize(alarms_number)

for (var i=0; i<argument0; i++)
{
    custom_alarm[i, 0] = -1;
    custom_alarm[i, 1] = -1;
}
```

script `custom_alarms_step`. Call it from `Step Begin` event

```
/// custom_alarms_step()

var sz = array_height_2d(custom_alarm);

for (var i=0; i<sz; i++)
{
    if custom_alarm[i, 0] != -1
    {
        custom_alarm[i, 0]--;    // Counter
        if custom_alarm[i, 0] = 0
        {
            custom_alarm[i, 0] = -1;
            if script_exists(custom_alarm[i, 1])
                script_execute(custom_alarm[i, 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

script `custom_alarm_set`. Use it for start alarm

```
/// custom_alarm_set(alarm, time, script)

var sz = array_height_2d(custom_alarm);

if argument0 < sz
{
    custom_alarm[argument0, 0] = max(-1, argument1);
    custom_alarm[argument0, 1] = argument2;
}
else
{
    show_message("Out of range (alarm " + string(argument0) + "). Max alarm id: " + string(sz - 1));
}
```

script `custom_alarm_get_current`. Use if you want get current value.

```
/// custom_alarm_get_current(alarm)

var sz = array_height_2d(custom_alarm);

if argument0 < sz
{
    return custom_alarm[argument0, 0];
}
else
{
    show_message("Out of range (alarm " + string(argument0) + "). Max alarm id: " + string(sz - 1));
}
```

Example of use:

```
alarm_start(5, room_speed * 10, your_action);
```

where `your_action` - name of the script which will be executed.

P.S. This code is for GameMaker Studio, not for GM 8.

P.P.S. Link to example: [click](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/gml/custom_alarms.gmz)